# What is wrong with my Maven Config?

Tags: java, maven-2, sonarqube

I want to checkout sonar, so I added the following snippet to my pom.xml the dependency part was taken from http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency

```
<profile>
     <id>sonar</id>
     <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
     <properties>
       <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sonar;create=true</sonar.jdbc.url>
       <sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
       </sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>
       <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
       <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
       <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:8080/sonar</sonar.host.url>
     </properties>
     <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Unfortunatly the error persists

```
Embedded error: Missing:
----------
1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

I also followed the suggestion to add the missing jar manually to the repository, which had no effect.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I verified that tools.jar has been added to my local repository. In debug mode maven shows the error:

```
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  group:artifact:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME env var set? Does it point to JDK and not JRE?

Comment: @mindas Yes, JAVA_HOME was set during mvn install:install-file

Comment: You might try to run mvn with -X param. It is overly verbose, but can lead to some clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running this in eclipse?  If the answer is yes, this is an annoying and very misunderstood problem.  Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756299/maven-3-artifact-problem/5756446#5756446)

You may not be pointing eclipse to the right jre/jdk when you're starting up (this is something you didn't necessarily configure rather was Windows)

Answer (score 1):

A problem I had once was different location of `tools.jar` under Mac OS. Here's the profiles section to solve the problem:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java-home-parent-lib-tools-jar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>java-home-parent-classes-classes-jar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <file>
                <exists>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

However I am not sure this is something you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

If your JAVA_HOME points to your jdk (e.g.`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_33`), your **tools.jar** configuration (`${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar`) indicates that there should be a **tools jar** with the following path: `/usr/lib/jvm/lib/tools.jar`.

If you change the tools jar path to ${java.home}/lib/tools.jar and verify that in your `JAVA_HOME/lib` there is the **tools.jar** file, it should work.

[There](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-104?focusedCommentId=300348&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-300348) you can find the related jira.