# mvn build could not find com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 osx

Tags: maven, jar

I'm currently working in eclipse on a project for a customer. When trying to deploy a run conviction with maven I get the following error:

> Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../Classes/classes.jar

It adds automatically the class path after it had rund. Obviously the `classes.jar` is not present. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694303/build-error-missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-6)

Comment: Refactor that code to get rid of tools jar need?...For JDK 9+ there does not exist any tools jar anymore ...this code will break for the next step of migration...